# Able to assign a macros but not compare

Tags: objective-c

While writing some code in objective c I am able to assign a macros (#define ) value to an int but the compiler doesn't allow me compare an int with a macros value.

```
if (appconst.DEVICE_TYPE == IPAD) {// where IPAD is a macro  
        [cell.title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    }else{

       [cell.title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    }
```

Parse Issue Group
/Users/libsys/projects/LSearch/LSearch/LSMain.m:425:33: Expected ')'
/Users/libsys/projects/LSearch/LSearch/LSConstants.h:42:15: Expanded from macro 'iPad'
/Users/libsys/projects/LSearch/LSearch/LSMain.m:425:8: To match this '('
/Users/libsys/projects/LSearch/LSearch/LSMain.m:425:37: Expected expression

on the other hand

```
appconst.DEVICE_TYPE=IPAD;
```

is legal.
Why??

Comment: Show the code and the compile error you see

Comment: Can you show your `appconst.DEVICE_TYPE` and `IPAD` definitions.

Comment: appconst is an object of constant class having @property int DEVICE_TYPE     and      IPAD is a macro defined as - #define IPAD 0;

Comment: @Sarasranglt take the `;` out of that definition i.e `#define IPAD 0`

Comment: @sbarow u were right !! it did work. But why dint the compiler generate any warning or error for the #define having the semicolon(;). Just want to understand it if you know why it happened.

Comment: @Sarasranglt to be honest I am not actually sure, I have asked the question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022213/colon-after-define-in-objective-c