# Colon after #define in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macros

In Objective-C you can define macros using the `#define`

```
#define kSomeMacro 1024
```

and then use that macro for something like this...

```
if (kSomeMacro == 1024) {
   ....
}
```

However if you define your macro with a colon on the end

```
#define kSomeMacro 1024;
```

Then the if statement won't work. What is the reasoning behind this and why doesn't the complier complain if you put  a `;` when defining the macro?

Comment: Because it is a simple text replacement. Thus, `if (1024; == 1024) {` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are just replaced by their definition. When you `#define k 1024;` and write `if(k==1024)...` what the compiler actually sees is:

```
if(1024; == 1024) ...
```

which doesn't compile.

The compiler doesn't complain because sometimes you may actually want to add a semicolon (`;` is called semicolon, not colon, which is `:`) to your macro.